# Cant login in https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/

Tags: paypal, sandbox

Yes, I have the test accounts in developer tool

And it was working fine today (2016, November 11) early, the last test was like at 3:30pm.

I was buying things (sandbox) and worked fine, but after 4 pm, when i try to buy something, the POST sends me to the sandbox main page, not the one with the item description, amount, etc...

Also, I try to login into the test facilitator or buyer account on sandbox, and I get this query string:

```
sandbox.paypal.com/signin?resType=code&failedBecause=securityTokenError
```

I don't know what happened, it was working fine today in the morning, before some final test I was coding something not related to the payments so I can't edit something about the buying code.

I even created a new paypal account, created the test users in developers tool, still the same

Comment: Seems like your token is not valid anymore? Have you tried resetting it?

Comment: even if is a fresh new main paypal account?

also, i never put a token in the code, is a simple POST to sandbox paypal (no IPN, PDT, etc)

To be sincere, i dont know whitch token i need to reset, but i'll search about it

Comment: (Disclaimer: I work for PayPal.)

There was a system issue with login at sandbox at the time you posted. See https://www.paypal-notify.com/eventnotification/event_details_popup?eventId=7609 for more information. This should be resolved now.